# How to debug azure service bus messaging?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I work in team with several developers. They have running service with listener on queue 'test'. I have the listener too. But I can't get the brokeredMessage on my listener.
Can I turn off other listeners to get brokeredMessage for my service? Can I use policy for it?
I've created debug policy and use the connecting string from here. Also I checked out `listen` option for development but I see some listener catch the brokeredMessage again. How to resolve it? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a queue 'test' set-up in Azure Service Bus, and you have multiple listeners re-acting to a message when it's posted, is that right?

If you're using an Azure Service Bus queue, then when a message is posted to it, it will stay there until a listener removes it from the queue for processing.  When that happens, the message is no longer available for another listener to receive it, as the intention is that the message is only processed once.

If you want to have multiple listeners watch for and re-act to a message appearing on the queue, maybe to process different things for the message, like one listener to check stock and another listener to process payment for example, then you might want to look at using the Topics/Subscriptions facility within the Service Bus - this allows you to create different subscriptions using rules, that can help you manage the multiple processing of a message by multiple listeners.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, you are right for several listeners we should use `Topics/Subscriptions` but here I need only one listener. And the problem is only in dev environment we have several listeners because several devs works on it. I need solution if I run listener locally I should get all brokeredMessages locally

Comment: ... then you'd either need to stop the other listeners, or create a separate queue for your use.

Comment: I saw in `Shared access policies` I can add debuggerPolicy and turn off listen option for devPolicy It should help me but I think other listeners should be restarted to use new policy rules

Comment: Ok, can I use sessions? If we have separate namespace like `vasyl` (name of developer)  session name for sender and receiver for each developer. I think it can help. What do you think?